# To find the best fitted HMM with depmixs4, how many times do I need to perform set.seed and fit.mod?

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models

```
    set.seed(123)
mod <- depmix(q[(i):(252*10-1+i),2] ~ 1, data = q[(i):(252*10-1+i),], nstates = 3, family = gaussian())

    fit.mod <- fit(mod)
```

I'm trying to find the best fitted HMM here. But setting set.seed differently would give different results on AIC. So does doing fit.mod multiple times.

Are these two steps all necessary? Is there a common standard as to how many times are needed to perform it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Chp, your above code is not completely reproducible. Where is `depmix()` coming from?

Comment: Hi, it's in the package depmixS4